# Joining the elements(integers) in a list

Tags: python, list

I want to join the elements in this list, L, and store the result in a variable k.
such that

```
L=[1,1,0,1,0]
k=11010
```

Comment: Please tag the language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python (like I suspect [and a previous question of yours was on python]), this isn't very difficult.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
xs = ""
for i in x:
    xs+=str(i)
print(xs) #As string
```

If you want to get it as an integer, you can add

```
k = int(xs)
```

As a function, this would be:

```
def makeIntFromList(x):
    xs = ""
    for i in x:
        xs+=i
    return int(xs)
```

Or, you can use **`join()`**.

```
def joinElementsToInt(x):
   return int("".join([str(i) for i in x]))
```

Comment: **Use `join`.** There's no reason for you to build this out manually.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
var k, L=[1,1,0,1,0];
    k = L.join("");
```

will do the job.